# QgsCoordinateTransform causes crash in processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, copy, transform

I want to perform a `QgsCoordinateTransform` on a `QgsGeometry` object and do some operations on this afterwards. I am doing this in a processing script and am getting the original `QgsGeometry` object from a `QgsSpatialIndex` with `flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries` set.

So basically I am doing

```py
overlay_geom = QgsGeometry(overlay_layer_idx.geometry(id))
overlay_geom.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(source_layer_crs, overlay_layer_crs, QgsProject.instance()))
nearest_point_geom = overlay_geom.nearestPoint(source_geom)
```

and it causes QGIS to crash with no informations provided. Tested on 3.16 and 3.28.

How can I transform my `QgsGeometry` object and do an operation on this afterwards?

*I'd have a workaround by simply using the native *reproject* algorithm, but want to avoid it, because it makes the `parameterAsSource` input unusable and forces to use `parameterAsLayer` instead.*

Here is the script I am actually using narrowed down to the essentials. Its working fine when both inputs have the same CRS, but will crash if not.

Edit: Just figured out it is not actually the transformation causing the crash but the next operation on the transformed geometry. And it is only crashing when reprojecting to 4326. But it does work with 4326 when both inputs have this crs and therefore no transformation is done.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import processing, math
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsProcessing, QgsSpatialIndex, QgsGeometry, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsCoordinateTransform,
                       QgsFeatureSink, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink, QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource)

class TransformTest(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    SOURCE_LYR = 'SOURCE_LYR'
    OVERLAY_LYR = 'OVERLAY_LYR'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.SOURCE_LYR, self.tr('Points'), [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint]))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.OVERLAY_LYR, self.tr('Lines'), [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]))
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT, self.tr('Test')))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        source_layer = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.SOURCE_LYR, context)
        source_layer_vl = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.SOURCE_LYR, context)
        overlay_layer = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.OVERLAY_LYR, context)
        overlay_layer_vl = self.parameterAsLayer(parameters, self.OVERLAY_LYR, context)
        output_layer_fields = source_layer.fields()
        
        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(parameters, self.OUTPUT, context,
                                               output_layer_fields, 2, # LineString = 2
                                               source_layer.sourceCrs())
                
        total = 100.0 / source_layer.featureCount() if source_layer.featureCount() else 0
        
        source_layer_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(source_layer_vl.crs().authid())
        overlay_layer_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(overlay_layer_vl.crs().authid())
        
        overlay_layer_idx = QgsSpatialIndex(overlay_layer.getFeatures(), flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)
        
        for current, source_feat in enumerate(source_layer.getFeatures()):
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break
            
            nearest_lines = overlay_layer_idx.nearestNeighbor(source_feat.geometry().centroid().asPoint(), neighbors = 1, maxDistance = -1)
            
            for nearest_line_id in nearest_lines:
                new_feat = QgsFeature(output_layer_fields)
                attridx = 0
                for attr in source_feat.attributes():
                    new_feat[attridx] = attr
                    attridx += 1
                    
                nearest_line_geom = overlay_layer_idx.geometry(nearest_line_id)
                if source_layer_vl.sourceCrs() != overlay_layer_vl.sourceCrs():
                    feedback.setProgressText('Doing transform now')
                    nearest_line_geom.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(source_layer_crs, overlay_layer_crs, context.transformContext()))
                    feedback.setProgressText('You see me, so the transform did not cause the crash')
                
                feedback.setProgressText('Will crash in 3.. 2.. 1.. go:')
                point_on_nearest_line = nearest_line_geom.nearestPoint(source_feat.geometry().centroid())
                feedback.setProgressText('You will not see me, because it already crashed')
        
                sqrDist, minDistPoint, afterVertex, leftOf = nearest_line_geom.closestSegmentWithContext(point_on_nearest_line.asPoint(),1)
                vertexOnSegment2 = nearest_line_geom.vertexAt(afterVertex)
                vertexOnSegment1 = nearest_line_geom.vertexAt(afterVertex - 1)
                segmentAngle = math.atan2(vertexOnSegment2.x() - vertexOnSegment1.x(), vertexOnSegment2.y() - vertexOnSegment1.y())
                segmentAngleDegree = math.degrees(segmentAngle) if segmentAngle > 0 else math.degrees(segmentAngle) + 180
                segmentgeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([vertexOnSegment1,vertexOnSegment2])
                perpendicularLinePoint1 = point_on_nearest_line.asPoint().project(10,segmentAngleDegree+90)
                perpendicularLinePoint2 = point_on_nearest_line.asPoint().project(10,segmentAngleDegree-90)
                perpendicularLineGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPolylineXY([perpendicularLinePoint1,perpendicularLinePoint2])
                
                new_feat.setGeometry(perpendicularLineGeom)
                
                sink.addFeature(new_feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))
        
        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}


    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return TransformTest()

    def name(self):
        return 'TransformTest'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('Transform Test')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr(self.groupId())

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Test'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr('Testing Transform')
```

Comment: "crash with no informations provided": Are you running QGIS in a terminal? There might be information printed there in case of crashing.

Comment: Try launching it from a terminal window.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that fully reproduces the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just found the answer, a simple mistake. I mixed up the order of arguments in the transformation. I set it to *reproject from targetcrs to sourcecrs*, instead the other way around. Of course this cannot work. So

```
nearest_line_geom.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(source_layer_crs, overlay_layer_crs, context.transformContext()))
```

should be

```
nearest_line_geom.transform(QgsCoordinateTransform(overlay_layer_crs, source_layer_crs, context.transformContext()))
```

Weird thing though it only crashed on EPSG:4326. Additionally I figured out that the next operation `point_on_nearest_line = nearest_line_geom.nearestPoint(source_feat.geometry().centroid())` actually caused the crash, not the transformation itself. And that `nearestPoint()` returns incorrect results anyway when using a geographic CRS.